# Как изменить сообщение к уже зафиксированой ревизии?

Tags: svn, контроль-версий

Иногда после того, как я уже зафиксировал ревизию или когда просматриваю историю фиксаций, командой `svn log`, хочу поправить или дополнить текст сообщений, которые могут ввести в заблуждение позже.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Это возможно сделать только имея непосредственный доступ к репозиторию, т.е. к файлам репозитория на сервере. Так что не достаточно иметь только рабочую копию проекта из репозитория.

Для наглядности и упрощения понимания все команды выполняются на одном и том же хосте и от одного и того же пользователя.

## Вступление

Создадим **тестовый** репозиторий для проекта `myproject`, который имеет только один файл `myfile.txt`:

```bash
$ cd ~/test && mkdir myproject && cd myproject
$ echo 'Hello world!' > myfile.txt
$ cd .. && mkdir svnrepos && cd svnrepos
$ svnadmin create myproject
$ svn import file:///home/ivanov/test/svnrepos/myproject -m 'Первая ревизия.'
```

Получим, а в данном случае переполучим рабочую копию:

```bash
$ cd .. && svn checkout file:///home/ivanov/test/svnrepos/myproject
```

## Собственно само изменение

### Первый способ

Без необходимости получения рабочей копии, но позволяет только заменить сообщение:

```bash
$ svnadmin setlog ~/test/svnrepos/myproject -r 1 --bypass-hooks <(echo 'Новое сообщение')
```

### Второй способ

По умолчанию изменение свойств запрещено. Для этого нужно в каталоге hook репозитория создать [перехватывающий](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) исполняемый скрипт (хук) `pre-revprop-change` из шаблона:

```bash
$ cd ~/test/svnrepos/myproject/hooks
$ mv pre-revprop-change.tmpl pre-revprop-change
$ chmod u+x pre-revprop-change
```

Теперь можно изменить свойство ревизии:

```bash
$ cd ~/test/myproject
$ svn propedit svn:log --revprop -r 1 --editor-cmd nano
```

Запуститься текстовый редактор `nano`, где надо отредактировать сообщение и сохранить его.

### Проверка результата

```bash
$ svn log -r 1 ~/test/myproject
```

Естествено вместо номера ревизии можно указывать `HEAD`, т.е. последнюю ревизию.